# Как настроить корректные пути в postcss-assets?

Tags: javascript, gulp, postcss

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть проект [вот такой](http://joxi.ru/5md7BX7hvgODMr) структурой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу настроить плагин postcss-assets, чтобы при команде background resolve('img.jpg') плагин автоматически прописывал пути к данному изображению.
в таске я указал вот такие настройки путей

```js
assets({
    basePath: 'dist/',
    loadPath: ['img/'],
    relativeTo: 'css/'
  }),
```

, но gulp [выдаёт ошибку](http://joxi.ru/DrlQBJQF4D8L7m)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

. Помогите пожалуйста. Что именно указал не так в настройках путей.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите `loadPath` в множественном числе: `loadPaths`.

Comment: Моё утверждение основано на том, что опция называется `loadPaths`, а не `loadPath`: https://github.com/assetsjs/postcss-assets#full-list-of-options